# Скелет для модуля под Opencart 3

Tags: php, cms, opencart, twig

Добрый день, никак не могу найти скелет или статью для разработки своего модуля под OpenCart 3. Если есть возможность, поделитесь, спасибо.

И попутно вопрос, как правильно добавлять на страницу home свои блоки (свою верстку)?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите любую статью по созданию модулей под **opencart 2.x**.

Отличия:

- файлы локализации более не надо посылать в представление через **$data**, они туда сами ходят.
- представление собирается через шаблонизатор **twig**, у него свой взгляд на построения файла, по этому надо ознакомится с ддокументацией по нему.
- файловая структура более всего похожа на версии 2.3+, файлы модулей лежат в папке **.. > extension > module**